# How to change JSON data Dynamically from with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, dynamic

I have an algorithm problem with JSON data to produce what I want.

I get some JSON data which I need to modify and display in client side with JS

JSON data:

```json
[
  {
    "ISTNO": "0000",
    "ATWCAN": "A",
    "COLNAME": "A1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0000",
    "ATWCAN": "B",
    "COLNAME": "A1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0000",
    "ATWCAN": "A",
    "COLNAME": "A1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0001",
    "ATWCAN": "D33D",
    "COLNAME": "B12"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0002",
    "ATWCAN": "GG14",
    "COLNAME": "C1C"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0003",
    "ATWCAN": "FFF-13",
    "COLNAME": "C13"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0004",
    "ATWCAN": "F",
    "COLNAME": "D1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0004",
    "ATWCAN": "ABB",
    "COLNAME": "D1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0004",
    "ATWCAN": "AAA",
    "COLNAME": "D1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0004",
    "ATWCAN": "AABA",
    "COLNAME": "D1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0005",
    "ATWCAN": "",
    "COLNAME": "E1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0006",
    "ATWCAN": "AGA",
    "COLNAME": "G1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0007",
    "ATWCAN": "",
    "COLNAME": "AFA"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0008",
    "ATWCAN": "ABA",
    "COLNAME": "FFFX"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0008",
    "ATWCAN": "ATR",
    "COLNAME": "FFFX"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0009",
    "ATWCAN": "BAB",
    "COLNAME": "BB"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0009",
    "ATWCAN": "ABA",
    "COLNAME": "BB"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0009",
    "ATWCAN": "ABBA",
    "COLNAME": "BB"
  }
]
```

My desired result:
[image: Result]

I need this table above so I need change data with JS

I tried to do it but it works wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/ah04b2f9/6/

```
    var aElements = [];
  var maxRow = 4;
  for (var i = 0; i < maxRow; i++) {
    var oElement = [];
    for (var t = 0; t < objData.length; t++) {
      if (objData[t + 1] !== undefined) {
        while (objData[t].ISTNO === objData[t + 1].ISTNO) {
          if (objData[t].Flag !== "X") {
            oElement[objData[t].COLNAME] = objData[t].ATWCAN;
          }
          objData[t + 1].Flag = "X";
          objData.splice(t, 1);
          t++;
          if (objData[objData.length - 1] === objData[t]) {
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        // oElement[objData[t].COLNAME] = objData[t].ATWCAN;
      }

      if (objData[t].Flag2 !== "X" && objData[t].Flag !== "X") {
        oElement[objData[t].COLNAME] = objData[t].ATWCAN;
        objData[t].Flag2 = "X";
      } else {
        //oElement[objData[t].COLNAME] = objData[t].ATWCAN;
      }

    }

    for (var a1 = 0; a1 < objData.length; a1++) {
      objData[a1].Flag = undefined;
    }

    aElements.push(oElement);
  }
  console.log(aElements);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified method that:

A. determines row index of every object in the json array

B. forms an array of objects (one object per row) that contain the desired "column name: value" pairs.

It should be straightforward to convert this array into an HTML table.

```js
const jsonData = [
  {
    "ISTNO": "0000",
    "ATWCAN": "A",
    "COLNAME": "A1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0000",
    "ATWCAN": "B",
    "COLNAME": "A1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0000",
    "ATWCAN": "A",
    "COLNAME": "A1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0001",
    "ATWCAN": "D33D",
    "COLNAME": "B12"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0002",
    "ATWCAN": "GG14",
    "COLNAME": "C1C"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0003",
    "ATWCAN": "FFF-13",
    "COLNAME": "C13"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0004",
    "ATWCAN": "F",
    "COLNAME": "D1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0004",
    "ATWCAN": "ABB",
    "COLNAME": "D1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0004",
    "ATWCAN": "AAA",
    "COLNAME": "D1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0004",
    "ATWCAN": "AABA",
    "COLNAME": "D1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0005",
    "ATWCAN": "",
    "COLNAME": "E1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0006",
    "ATWCAN": "AGA",
    "COLNAME": "G1"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0007",
    "ATWCAN": "",
    "COLNAME": "AFA"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0008",
    "ATWCAN": "ABA",
    "COLNAME": "FFFX"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0008",
    "ATWCAN": "ATR",
    "COLNAME": "FFFX"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0009",
    "ATWCAN": "BAB",
    "COLNAME": "BB"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0009",
    "ATWCAN": "ABA",
    "COLNAME": "BB"
  },
  {
    "ISTNO": "0009",
    "ATWCAN": "ABBA",
    "COLNAME": "BB"
  }
];

// determine row index of each object in jsonData array
let lastIstno;
let row = 0;
const dataWithRows = jsonData.map(el => {
  const istno = el.ISTNO;
  row = (istno !== lastIstno) ? 0 : row + 1;
  lastIstno = istno;
  return { iRow: row, ...el };
});



// create array of objects (one object per row)
// containing `COLNAME : ATWCAN` pairs
const results = dataWithRows.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (typeof acc[item.iRow] === 'undefined') {
    acc[item.iRow] = {};
  }
  acc[item.iRow][item.COLNAME] = item.ATWCAN;
  return acc;
}, []);

const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
pre.innerText = `dataWithRows: ` +
  JSON.stringify(dataWithRows, null, 2);
pre.innerText += '\n\nresults: ' + JSON.stringify(results, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that builds on two simple helper functions.  `group` accepts a function and returns a new function that takes an array and groups the elements of that array into sub-arrays for which the function yields the same value.  When we call it with `x => x .COLNAME`, we will group the original data into columns.

`transpose` flips an array over its main diagonal, filling missing entries with `undefined`.  This will turn our array of columns into an array of rows.

Our main function, `restructure` fetches the unique headers out of the data, and then combines `group` and `transpose` to create our list of rows.  It looks like this:

```js
// utility functions
const group = (fn) => (xs) =>
  Object .values (xs .reduce (
    (a, x) => ((a [fn (x)] = [... (a [fn (x)] || []), x]), a),
    {}
  ))

const transpose = m => 
  m [0] .map ((c, i) => m .map (r => r [i]))


// main function
const restructure = (xs) => ({
  headers: [... new Set (xs .map (x => x.COLNAME))],
  rows: transpose (group (x => x.COLNAME) (xs) .map (x => x .map (y => y .ATWCAN)))
})


// sample data
const input = [{ISTNO: "0000", ATWCAN: "A", COLNAME: "A1"}, {ISTNO: "0000", ATWCAN: "B", COLNAME: "A1"}, {ISTNO: "0000", ATWCAN: "A", COLNAME: "A1"}, {ISTNO: "0001", ATWCAN: "D33D", COLNAME: "B12"}, {ISTNO: "0002", ATWCAN: "GG14", COLNAME: "C1C"}, {ISTNO: "0003", ATWCAN: "FFF-13", COLNAME: "C13"}, {ISTNO: "0004", ATWCAN: "F", COLNAME: "D1"}, {ISTNO: "0004", ATWCAN: "ABB", COLNAME: "D1"}, {ISTNO: "0004", ATWCAN: "AAA", COLNAME: "D1"}, {ISTNO: "0004", ATWCAN: "AABA", COLNAME: "D1"}, {ISTNO: "0005", ATWCAN: "", COLNAME: "E1"}, {ISTNO: "0006", ATWCAN: "AGA", COLNAME: "G1"}, {ISTNO: "0007", ATWCAN: "", COLNAME: "AFA"}, {ISTNO: "0008", ATWCAN: "ABA", COLNAME: "FFFX"}, {ISTNO: "0008", ATWCAN: "ATR", COLNAME: "FFFX"}, {ISTNO: "0009", ATWCAN: "BAB", COLNAME: "BB"}, {ISTNO: "0009", ATWCAN: "ABA", COLNAME: "BB"}, {ISTNO: "0009", ATWCAN: "ABBA", COLNAME: "BB"}]


// demo
console .log (restructure (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

From this output, it should be easy enough to create a table.  Here we have a function that uses simple string manipulation and `innerHTML` to add the results to the DOM.  But you should be able to build something like this in whatever front-end technology you are using.

```js
const makeTable = (xs, {headers, rows} = restructure(xs)) => 
`<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>${headers .map (h => `<th>${h}</th>`) .join ('')}</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ${rows .map (
      row => `<tr>${row .map (
        cell => `<td>${cell || ''}</td>`
      ) .join ('')}</tr>`
    ) .join ('\n    ')}
  </tbody>
</table>`

document .getElementById ('result') .innerHTML = makeTable (input)
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse} td, th {border: 1px solid black; padding: .5em} th {background: #ccc}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<script>const group = (fn) => (xs) => Object .values (xs .reduce ((a, x) => ((a [fn (x)] = [... (a [fn (x)] || []), x]), a), {})); const transpose = m => m [0] .map ((c, i) => m .map (r => r [i])); const restructure = (xs) => ({headers: [... new Set (xs .map (x => x.COLNAME))], rows: transpose (group (x => x.COLNAME) (xs) .map (x => x .map (y => y .ATWCAN)))}); const input = [{ISTNO: "0000", ATWCAN: "A", COLNAME: "A1"}, {ISTNO: "0000", ATWCAN: "B", COLNAME: "A1"}, {ISTNO: "0000", ATWCAN: "A", COLNAME: "A1"}, {ISTNO: "0001", ATWCAN: "D33D", COLNAME: "B12"}, {ISTNO: "0002", ATWCAN: "GG14", COLNAME: "C1C"}, {ISTNO: "0003", ATWCAN: "FFF-13", COLNAME: "C13"}, {ISTNO: "0004", ATWCAN: "F", COLNAME: "D1"}, {ISTNO: "0004", ATWCAN: "ABB", COLNAME: "D1"}, {ISTNO: "0004", ATWCAN: "AAA", COLNAME: "D1"}, {ISTNO: "0004", ATWCAN: "AABA", COLNAME: "D1"}, {ISTNO: "0005", ATWCAN: "", COLNAME: "E1"}, {ISTNO: "0006", ATWCAN: "AGA", COLNAME: "G1"}, {ISTNO: "0007", ATWCAN: "", COLNAME: "AFA"}, {ISTNO: "0008", ATWCAN: "ABA", COLNAME: "FFFX"}, {ISTNO: "0008", ATWCAN: "ATR", COLNAME: "FFFX"}, {ISTNO: "0009", ATWCAN: "BAB", COLNAME: "BB"}, {ISTNO: "0009", ATWCAN: "ABA", COLNAME: "BB"}, {ISTNO: "0009", ATWCAN: "ABBA", COLNAME: "BB"}]</script>
```

The important thing about this solution is that it breaks our work down into manageable chunks.  In doing so, we have created two useful functions that we might reuse across many projects.